# Kinematics question regarding minimum journey time

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, velocity

Suppose there is a track length of 256 metres and there is a car whose maximum speed is 40 metres/second and can accelerate or regarding at the rate of 4 metres / second ^2 and it has to be at rest at the 256 metres position.

To have minimum journey length, is it necessary to reach maximum speed it can reach in 128 metres and then retard 128 metres or can it reach a certain speed less than the maximum speed and then move with constant velocity for some time and then retard.I tried forming an inequality with the time coming with the case mentioned above being greater than some assumed time t in a journey in which it also moves for some time with constant velocity and the result clearly showed the that assumption implied that it would be true for t<0 seconds. But this got me thinking is it true for all distance or it came true for this scenario only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is true for all distances, Since you made the calculation for 256m you can do it for a distance d, first calculate the time for no constant speed, and than for some time of constant speed.